# <a> tag with type button and btn-primary class is not working in MacOS safari

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, safari

Anchor tag with type button and btn-primary class is not working in MacOS safari but same code is working fine in chrome , edge browser

`<a class="btn btn-primary " style="border-radius: 25px;" type="button" href="#"  <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>> Download Client</a>`

MACOS safari browser

[image: IOS error]

chrome browser

[image]

please suggest me the right way to implement the  tag with bootstrap

Comment: Why do you need type=button?

Comment: if i remove type=button on the anchor tag , will it work ?? @Arcteezy

Comment: It should. Because i have used bootstrap in MacOS and it works fine. BTW, is that a typo? Your icon is inside the <a> tag.

Comment: thank you it worked @Arcteezy, post it as answer ill accept it

Comment: the @MonkeyScript answer work for me! 

Remove the type="button" in the <button> or <a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `type="button"` and it should work.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 25px;" href="#"> 
    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download Client
</a>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Its work!

THK!!!